# Getting Deprecated Warning while importing module parser

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

I am getting below error while running code. How to fix this?

DeprecationWarning: The parser module is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of Python

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, the `parser` module was deprecated in version 3.9, and will eventually be removed.

Most of its functionality can be found in the [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html); it shouldn't be too hard to rewrite the code to use `ast`, although it's not a simple search-and-replace for function names. It depends on what the`parser` module is being used for.

Fortunately, you still have some time to sort this out (and the module isn't going to disappear from Python versions which currently support it).